# Any issues using HTTPContext outside of web project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

We have a web application with access to Business logic and data access in separate projects.

The way it is designed, key values is never passed to data access layer or business logic. Instead business layer has a class which contains public read only property through which DAL layer access the values.

Business logic layer is in a different project. Web project gets the reference.
Business logic layer has this class : `Public NotInheritable Class clsUserProfile`
Which has this property:

```
Public ReadOnly Property AgencyCode() As Integer

    Get
        If clsAppInfo.IsWebApplication Then
            If (HttpContext.Current.Session(_AgencyCodeKey) Is Nothing) Then
                Return 0
            Else
                Return HttpContext.Current.Session(_AgencyCodeKey)
            End If
        Else
            Return AgencyCodeWIN
        End If
    End Get

End Property
```

/****** For windows Agency Code is declared as shared

```
 Public Shared Property AgencyCodeWIN() As Integer
        Get
            Return _AgencyCodeWIN
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _AgencyCodeWIN = value
        End Set

    End Property
```

/************
To determine whether it is a web app or not .......

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property IsWebApplication() As Boolean
    Get
        If AppCodeWIN IsNot String.Empty Then      
                 'Desk top App is required to pass AppInfo
            Return False
        Else                                                  
                 'Web App is default
            Return True
        End If
    End Get
End Property
```

Will the data will be overwritten when multiple users login. 
Many people say that it is not advisable, but cannot find any provable reason as to why it is not recommended?

If anybody can give clear reasons that would be great.

Thanks,
sandy .

Comment: I think the reason people would suggest against this is because you've split the responsibility of the getter and setter for AgencyCode. In other words, `clsUserProfile#AgencyCode` requires `HttpContext.Current` to exist, but you've hacked it to return a special value **if it doesn't exist**.  Another reason people may complain is that Session grabs a lock per request ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479041.aspx)).

Comment: thanks jim. I have been given assignment to prove that why using httpcontext outside of web project is a bad idea. With the above methodology, for a web project if I assign session variables I get data. If it is a non-web project I can set the values using AgencycodeWin. Data is not overwritten when multiple users login. So why it is not a good to take it outside this way? I have asked to prove that it is a bad design. Greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: You can apply the [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) to this. To clarify my previous comment, `clsUserProfile` is tightly coupled to `HttpContext.Current` and to whatever code is calling it. You're not encapsulating a _UserProfile_ if on one line of code you call `AgencyCode`, some other code modifies the session, and calling `AgencyCode` again a few lines later yields a different result. Granted, the user of this session would have to do something that updates that value in your situation, but it's not good design for all situations.

Answer (score 0):

> Will the data will be overwritten when multiple users login

No

> Many people say that it is not advisable, but cannot find any provable reason as to why it is not recommended?

In this context, adding a third running mode would be a pain.

In fact, your class clsUserProfile should not be aware of your application running mode (webapp or desktop). It even should not know about HttpContext and Session or choose between two running modes, just to get an AgencyCode.

clsUserProfile should be a plain C# object. The running mode should be handled at a higher level in your app.

Comment: thank you. what can be third running mode. Say web services, if I enable sessionmode it works fine. I have been given the assignment to find holes in the above methodology if any. Other than like you said, outside class should not have the control of httpContext, and that it is a bad design, I have been asked to prove that it is a bad design. Greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Unit testing should prove to be a tricky running mode. I guess it would be a pain to unit test web and windows running mode. 
The design is not bad because it does not work (it seems to), but because it is very difficult to understand and modify (just for an int property, which I assume us set once and for all during connection process)